# Synchronizing multiple datagridviews with same source list

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding

I'm currently buiding an application on which I have 5 DataGridViews which are all displaying the same information which is coming from a BindingList.

DataGridView 1 is an Administration-grid where I can modify data from the list.
DataGridView 2 through 5 are essentially Read-Only grids where I do not need to modify any data, but in each of these DataGridViews I need to be able to select a different line, to display some status information.

I have tried linking all of the DataGridViews to the same BindingList but then I have the issue that when I select a line in DGV1, it highlights it as well on the other DGV's, which I don't want.

So then I linked each individual DGV to a individual new BindingList with the original list as content.

```
grdAdmin.DataSource = new BindingList<myClass>(selectedList);
grd1.DataSource = new BindingList<myClass>(selectedList);
grd2.DataSource = new BindingList<myClass>(selectedList);
grd3.DataSource = new BindingList<myClass>(selectedList);
grd4.DataSource = new BindingList<myClass>(selectedList);
```

That solves the issue of being able to select different lines on each DGV, but when I modify the list in my Administration-DGV, the updates are not automatically pushed towards the other DGV's, which is logical since they are separate instances.
To solve this I could relink the original list to all of the individual instances, but then it loses the selection in the DGV which as a result doesn't show me the correct status anymore.

I could probably solve this by checking the DGV's first and remembering the selected line in each DGV and reselecting it when I refresh the bindinglists, but that's quite messy.

So I was wondering what the correct approach would be?
In the ideal scenario I have a List which:

- is being modified from the admin DGV
- automatically updates all of the other DGV's without relinking
- allows me to select individual lines in each DGV

I'm looking forward to your thoughts.
Thanks

*** UPDATE ***
I just noticed that the other DGV's actually do update except it's not showing unless I refresh them. So I've used this as a temporary solution but I'm still curious to know if I can still improve this or what the "proper" way would be to do this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'the updates are not automatically pushed towards the other DGV's,'? Do you mean items added/removed to/from selectedList or changed property values of items in the list?

Comment: I meant that when I update a value in the Admin-DGV, in the other DGV's that value would not be updated. That is until I found that I needed to refresh the DGV.

Comment: So are you changing a property value of a `myClass` instance? Does myClass implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: Without implementing the interface INotifyPropertyChanged in myClass is impossible for the other BindingList instances to raise an event, so simply implement that interface in myClass.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you @Steeeve

Answer (score 0):

Put 5 different BindingSources between the source and the various DataGridView. They maintain their own sense of position and other controls can be bound to them, but they update a common list

```
grdAdmin.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = selectedList };
grd2.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = selectedList };
grd2.ReadOnly = true;
...
```

It'd also probably be easier to make selectedList a DataTable, as it already implements all the necessary events

[image]